# Adding XMLElements

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to add entries to an existing specific xml doc that looks basically alike:

```
<body>
 <setting>
  <app name="notepad.exe" folder= "c:\windows\system32\" owner="peter"/>
  <app name="calc.exe" folder= "c:\windows\system32\" age="4"/>
 </setting>
</body>
```

The problem I have that I want to add multiple app entries, each width their own attributes, like owner or age etc. (ea not overwritting a single one).

I was thinking of

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
System.xml.XmlElement appnew = new system.Xml.XmlElement("<app name=\"write.exe\" folder="\c:\\windows\\system32\\\"")
```

Then later add the XmlElement to the sttings section however XMLElement can not be set like that, so I wonder how to add equal node names?

Comment: Try : XElement setting = doc.Descendants("app").FirstOrDefault(); setting.Add(new XElement("app", new object[] {new XAttribute("name","notepad.exe"), XAttribute("folder","c:\windows\system32\"),XAttribute("owner","peter")}));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following

```
  var doc =
      new XDocument( 
        new XElement("body",
          new XElement("setting",
            new XElement("app", new XAttribute("age", "4")),
            new XElement("app", new XAttribute("owner", "bitchiko"))
     )));
```

In case you have **existing** `XDocument` and are trying to **add** new `app` element. Then try following

```
var doc= new XDocument(...);
var settingsXElement = doc.Descendants("setting").Single();
settingsXElement.Add(new XElement("app", new XAttribute("owner", "tchelidze")));
```

Comment: That would work for a new document, but i want to "add" such entries.
as i have an excisting Xdocument, sorry i should have written that more clear, i'll edit the question a bit

Comment: Ah thanks that was what i needed i got close to it over-here but that one nailed it.